# Understanding the UserDefaults register method

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

First of all, let me say that this is NOT a complaint, I just want to understand how does the `register(defaults: [])` method works.

I'm using the UserDefaults `register(defaults: [])` method inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method to register the default value of all of my UseDefault keys, everything is working fine as expected.

My question is, why is that the values in the `register(defaults: [])` method do not reset everytime the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is called?

I do not want them to rest I'm just trying to understand why.

I have the following code...

```
func application(...didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...) -> Bool {

    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
        keyUserName:"",
        keyHasCar:false
        ])
}
```

Here is why my confusion, when the app runs, it saves the default values as expected, then, if the values get modified later somewhere in the app and right-after the app is killed and relaunched, the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called again but the values do not get reset, but if I add a new key to the array it does get saved but the rest of the keys do not get reset only the new one is added with its default value.

Again, I do not want the values to reset, I just need to understand how does `register` method works.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the documentation for `register(defaults:)`:

> If there is no registration domain, one is created using the specified dictionary, and NSRegistrationDomain is added to the end of the search list.
>
> The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk; you need to call this method each time your application starts.

What this means is that the registered defaults act as a fallback to the normal, user defaults that you are working with. The registered defaults do not overwrite or replace the standard user defaults.

When you attempt to lookup a key from `UserDefaults.standard`, if the key isn't there, then it is looked up in the registered defaults and that result (if any) is returned.

Once you set a value in `UserDefaults.standard`, of course it is that value that is returned for the key. If you remove the key from `UserDefaults.standard` then the registered default is used again.