# Saving Date in UserDefaults of the first time the App was opened

Tags: swift, date, nsuserdefaults, appdelegate

I am trying to set the `Date()` the very first time an App is opened. This will be set in `UserDefaults`.

I used `register()` to save the date in UserDefault. The problem is.. this value seems to be saving on *every* launch, which defeats the purpose of UserDefaults.register.

Here is my code:

```
let initialOpen: NSDictionary = ["FirstOpen" : Date()]
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: initialOpen as! [String : AnyObject])

let firstOpenDate = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "FirstOpen")
print("First Opened: \(firstOpenDate)")
```

I am calling this within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

**How can I record the time that the App is launched for the first time in UserDefaults?**

Comment: If you wish to understand what `register(defaults:)` does, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683730/understanding-the-userdefaults-register-method/53684212#53684212

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. There's no need for `register(defaults:)`.
2. Don't use `value(forKey:)` to read data from `UserDefaults`.

All you need to do is first check if the date has been set, if not, set it.

```
if let firstOpen = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "FirstOpen") as? Date {
    print("The app was first opened on \(firstOpen)")
} else {
    // This is the first launch
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "FirstOpen")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the register(defaults:) tip. This works. Question: "2. Don't use value(forKey:) to read data from UserDefaults." Okay. What should I use to read date from UserDefaults?

Comment: Look at the reference documentation for `UserDefaults`. Besides `object(forKey:)` shown my answer there are several others that return specific data types.